# Stages in genetic programming

Tags: genetic-programming

When evolving a genetic program, how is the required time distributed between different stages in development? I mean: Is 90 percent of the time devoted to becoming a little bit better than random programs, after which improving the program to the final version is not very computation-intensive?

Comment: Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming and http://www.genetic-programming.org/

Answer (score 1):

Most metaheuristics (including genetic algorithms I think) have a progress like the green and red lines on this image. They try to reach the best score as fast as possible and it gets harder and hard to find a better score.

[image: plot]

However, some (like simulated annealing, the blue line) can be told the amount of time they 'll be given and behave differently based upon that. In that case you can get a more linear like line.

Comment: So the question is: *Is your genetic algorithm aware how total time it's given and does it use that?*

Answer (score 0):

Generally progress is quicker earlier, with progress slowing in later generations. But it does depend on the nature of the problem. Why not test it out on a few different problems and plot the progress?

Answer (score 0):

An approximate indication to this can be the size of the program. If the program size becomes stable but you notice that fitness is still improving, then most likely all random programs were weeded out. The fitness improvement can therefore be attributed to minor numerical changes in say the coefficients.